# How can Chrome extension get a callback when the browser starts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need a way in my Chrome extension to know when the browser is starting up, so that it can automatically open an html page. Is there a mechanism in Chrome extension API that can get me this facility?

I need this functionality for a personal extension of mine, that I use only on my computer. So it's ok if this can be accomplished through a hack. My extension would like to know when the browser has started.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you want the tab to open when Chrome is started up, you can just include the code: `chrome.tabs.create({url:"someUrl"});` in your background.js file or if you want it to open everytime a new window opens, you can include the previous code plus an extra event listener to the new window event like this:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
chrome.tabs.create({url:"someUrl"});
})
```

Answer (score 10):

Scripts in [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) start only one time on each browser start, so you just need to add background page to your extension to handle browser start.

Comment: Technically speaking, an extension update will also fire that.

Comment: I believe that the background page get deactivated after a few minutes of not being used, and when it is loaded again (i.e. an event is fired), all of its code will be run again. So the code will likely be run much more often than just once on browser start.

Comment: @Scruffy is right in 2022, but @KAdot was right too in 2012. Just as a clarification to future readers: `Service workers are short-lived execution environments. In more practical terms, an extension's service worker will start up, do some work, and get terminated repeatedly throughout a user's browser session. This poses a challenge to extension developers accustomed to long-lived background pages as application data is not immediately available in global variables.` (from: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#state)